# How to Create Chat Connection to backend server for Web base application using socket.io in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

i have implemented code using socket.io in react native application to my our webserver but i sending message through the app but this.socket.on() and this.socket.emit() is not working in my application.

here is the code.....

in my main screen.......

in Chat screen file.

```js
componentDidMount(){

this.socket = SocketIOClient("https://xxx.xxxxxxxx.com");
    this.socket.on("sendOneToOneMsg",(chatMessage) => {

      console.log('response',chatMessage);
    });

    console.log(this.state.messages)

  }


submitChatMessage(chatMessage){



    var data = { 
        searchFriendsAuto : 0,
        friendOrNotData : 1, 
        action : 'send',
        reciverUserId : this.props.RecieverID,
        senderUserId : this.props.SenderID,
        msg : chatMessage,
        userName : this.props.userName, 
        is_type : 0,
        message_type : 1
      }

    this.socket.emit("sendOneToOneMsg",data);
    this.setState({chatMessage:""})

  }
```

submit function used on TextInput submit button.

but still messaging not working when i send message nothing works any solutions?

Comment: can you check tgghis, it explains greatly :

https://kriss.io/buiding-chat-app-with-react-native-and-socketio-cjzi03e3e005bdes19yy89z7d/

Comment: no it did not work? your link is right but code only for local web server.

Comment: how to connect with live backend server for messaging functioinlaity send and recieve in mobile app